# Solaris .so file dependency

Tags: shared-libraries, solaris, ldd

I need to find which are all the exe/so file is dependent on another so file. For example, libsample.so file is used by libs1.so, libs2.so and sample.exe. I know we can get the dependency of libs1.so, libs2.so and sample.exe by running ldd command. But the reverse is possible in any way? like I would like to get who are all dependent with libsample.so?

Under my project bin folder what are all the libs/exes are dependent with the libsample.so? can we find?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic library dependencies are stored in the `.dynamic` section of the ELF binary in question. They have the `NEEDED` tag and the value is the name of the dependency. For example:

```
$ elfdump -d /usr/bin/nc | head

Dynamic Section:  .dynamic
    index  tag              value    
      [0]  POSFLAG_1        0x1        [ LAZY ]
      [1]  NEEDED           0x61d      libresolv.so.2
      [2]  POSFLAG_1        0x1        [ LAZY ]
      [3]  NEEDED           0x63c      libdladm.so.1
      [4]  POSFLAG_1        0x1        [ LAZY ]
      [5]  NEEDED           0x65a      libuutil.so.1
      [6]  NEEDED           0x668      libc.so.1
```

These are immediate dependencies. In the `/usr/bin/nc` example above there are 4 such entries currently. If you run `ldd` on a dynamically linked binary it will give you recursive dependencies. In our example, `ldd /usr/bin/nc` prints 91 library dependencies in total (the main contributor being `libdladm.so.1` that depends on whole bunch of other libraries that in turn depend on other libraries, ...).

There is no central place in the system that would store this dependency information. It is all distributed in the ELF binaries. So, to get the dependents (as opposed to dependencies) of a executable or library, it is necessary to traverse the relevant part of the directory tree and accumulate them. This should be easily scriptable e.g. using the find(1) command.